# Unicode messing with the spacing in my chess board

Tags: ruby, unicode

The unicode chess pieces create an odd spacing and messes up the size of the board. Is there anything I can do with Ruby to fix this?

```
class GameBoard 
   attr_accessor :white_king, :white_queen, :white_rook, :white_bishop, :white_knight, :white_pawn, :black_king, :black_queen, :black_rook, :black_knight, :black_bishop, :black_pawn, :board 
      def initialize
      @white_king = "♔"
            @white_queen = "♕"
            @white_rook = "♖"
            @white_bishop = "♗"
            @white_knight = "♘"
            @white_pawn = "♙"
            @black_king = "♚"
            @black_queen = "♛"
            @black_rook = "♜"
            @black_bishop = "♝"
            @black_knight = "♞"
            @black_pawn = "♟" 
            @board = Array.new(8) { Array.new(8," ") }
            end
            def display
              @board.each { |i|
                print "\n"
                @a = "+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+"
                puts @a
                i.each {|n|
                  print "| #{n}  "
                  } 
                  print "|"}
                  print "\n"
                  print @a
            end 

            def knight 
              @board[0][0] = @black_knight
              display
            end 
    end 
    J = GameBoard.new
    J.knight
```

this is the output, the knight seems to take up a space and a half. Maybe a way to change the size of a ruby space?

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| ♞  |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Don't you just need 3 or 5 horizontal slots, instead of 4 (so you can center it)?

Comment: I edited so you can see the output. No matter what I do the spacing will still be off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unicode also has different sized spaces you can use.

```
@board = Array.new(8) { Array.new(8,"  ") }
```

Using these spaces instead of a normal space when declaring the second parameter in the array makes it the same size as a Unicode chess piece.

```
U+0020  SPACE   foo bar     Depends on font, typically 1/4 em, often adjusted
U+00A0  NO-BREAK SPACE  foo bar     As a space, but often not adjusted
U+1680  OGHAM SPACE MARK    foo bar     Unspecified; usually not really a space but a dash
U+180E  MONGOLIAN VOWEL SEPARATOR   foo᠎bar     No width
U+2000  EN QUAD     foo bar     1 en (= 1/2 em)
U+2001  EM QUAD     foo bar     1 em (nominally, the height of the font)
U+2002  EN SPACE    foo bar     1 en (= 1/2 em)
U+2003  EM SPACE    foo bar     1 em
U+2004  THREE-PER-EM SPACE  foo bar     1/3 em
U+2005  FOUR-PER-EM SPACE   foo bar     1/4 em
U+2006  SIX-PER-EM SPACE    foo bar     1/6 em
U+2007  FIGURE SPACE    foo bar     “Tabular width”, the width of digits
U+2008  PUNCTUATION SPACE   foo bar     The width of a period “.”
U+2009  THIN SPACE  foo bar     1/5 em (or sometimes 1/6 em)
U+200A  HAIR SPACE  foo bar     Narrower than THIN SPACE
U+200B  ZERO WIDTH SPACE    foo​bar     Nominally no width, but may expand
U+202F  NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE   foo bar     Narrower than NO-BREAK SPACE (or SPACE)
U+205F  MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE   foo bar     4/18 em
U+3000  IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE   foo　bar     The width of ideographic (CJK) characters.
U+FEFF  ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE   foo﻿bar     No width (the character is invisible)
```